# Magento 2 set product image role programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-images

Hello and this is my code:

```
$imgURL = 'path/to/my/image.png';
$fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($mediaPath.'catalog/product'.$data['thumbnail_image'],['thumbnail', 'swatch'], false, false);
$product->setThumbnail($mediaPath.'catalog/product'.$imgURL);
$product->save();
```

What I want to achive, is to assign programmatically an image and set it as a thumbnail.
The above code, uploads the image, but it's role: the thumbnail and swatch are not selected. Not sure why ? See img:
[image]

Can you tell me  what am i doing wrong ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set explicitly the thumbnail, the following line is enough:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($mediaPath.'catalog/product'.$data['thumbnail_image'],['thumbnail', 'swatch'], false, false);
```

As for the swatch image, you have it wrong in the array, it should be "swatch_image" instead of "swatch". The following media types are available:

- image
- small_image
- thumbnail
- swatch_image

You should also consider resizing images after setting them this way by using *Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image*:

```
$this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image');
$this->imageHelper->resize($width, $height);
```

Also, check the *etc/view.xml* from your theme for more image ids ('wishlist_thumbnail', 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail', etc)