# How to programmatically add roles to product images?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-images

I need to insert Small, thumbnail and swatch roles to all existing product images, any solution? Thanks
[image]

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351851/78648

Answer (score 1):

Paste below code script in pub folder and try in your project.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
 
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
 
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get(State::class);
$state->setAreaCode('global');

$dir = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$mediaPath = $directory->getPath('media');
$imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail', 'swatch_image']; //this is for all images

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $count = 0;
        $galleryReadHandler = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler');
        $galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        $productFirstImage = '';
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            if ($count == 0) {
                $productFirstImage = $mediaPath."/catalog/product".$image->getFile();
            }
            $count ++;
        }
        if ($product->getId()) {
            if (file_exists($productFirstImage)) {
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($productFirstImage, $imageType, true);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code I tested and working fine.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Mohit Patel, this code replaced all my images with the default image. :)